# javascript equivalent to php unpack() function

Tags: php, javascript, phpjs

I am looking for the javascript equivalent of php [`unpack()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) function? can someone direct me please.
Thanks!

Comment: php.js has a [`pack()` implementation](http://phpjs.org/functions/pack:880) but apparently no `unpack()` :-S

Answer (score 1):

Here is an unpack function for JS:

https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/workbench/misc/unpack.js

Comment: The link is not available as of now. Here's [a related issue](https://github.com/kvz/locutus/issues/221) and the direct link to the js file: https://github.com/kvz/locutus/blob/98d264640c6a1586a1235d0f1da044c4c28a3752/workbench/misc/unpack.js It says it's not production ready.

Answer (score 1):

If nodejs (4.5/6.5) would be the environment, `Buffer` can partially achieve the functionality of `unpack()`:

```
const buf = Buffer.from([0, 0, 0, 5]);
// Prints: 83886080
console.log(buf.readInt32LE());
```

See its documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readint32le_offset_noassert

This is equivalent to:

```
 unpack('V', join('', array_map(function ($a) { return chr($a); }, [0, 0, 0, 5])));
```